# Why is my code complaining about DependencyProperty.UnsetValue if the property has value?

Tags: wpf, toggle

I'm trying to add a new trigger to a custom control in WPF programmatically by adding a new style. Control inherits from ToggleButton, and trigger should rely on IsCheckedProperty of the button. Even though I specifically assign value to IsChecked, InvalidOperationException is still thrown. Snippet:

```
protected BalanceSheetButton(OperationSummaryModel summaryModel, OperationFlow operationFlow, 
StackPanel mainPanel)
{
    this.IsChecked = true;
    RegisterStyle();
}

private void RegisterStyle()
{
    var a = ((DependencyObject)this).ReadLocalValue(IsCheckedProperty);
    var style = new Style();

    var trigger = new Trigger();
    trigger.Property = IsCheckedProperty;
    trigger.Setters.Add(new Setter { Property = ForegroundProperty, Value = this.Foreground });
    style.Triggers.Add(trigger);
    Style = style;
}
```

The exception:
'{DependencyProperty.UnsetValue}' is not a valid value for property 'IsChecked'.

this.ReadLocalValue(IsCheckedProperty) returns assigned value, so why would it complain about the UnsetValue?

I tried assigning a value to IsChecked specifically to no avail. Both this.GetValue(IsCheckedProperty) and this.ReadLocalValue(IsCheckedProperty) return the assigned value.

Comment: I don't think the error is in the code that you showed.

Comment: @Ostas What do you mean? The buttons are being created programmatically with a public method that calls this constructor. This is the only place where the custom style is assigned.

Comment: My bad, I tested it and was able to reproduce the problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to specify the value for the trigger.
Just add

```
trigger.Value = true;
```

the `UnsetValue` in the message was the default value for `trigger.Value`.

Comment: Thank you very much :) I would upvote it if I had the reputation, but this enabled me to add the style correcty.